# How does a web server decides if the request should be responded with HTTP response or HTTPS response?

Tags: http, https

When I type say `www.google.com`on my browser whether my browser sends an http request or https request. If request is on http but the requested resource is served by https does the server make a redirection ? Because if the request is http then the server is listening on port 80. So the connection established is between client port and port 80. Does the server creates a new connection if it has to serve something from 443 ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the server just redirects you ...